# Where do fractional points in UCI ranking come from?

Tags: rules, ranking, cycling

If you look at various UCI rankings, you often see riders that have non-integers as their rankings. For example, if you look at the [current UCI World Ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Current_Top_10_Men%27s_Road_Rankings_-_Individual&oldid=843632476) and this year's [UCI World Tour rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=2018_UCI_World_Tour&oldid=843989654#Points_standings), you can see Froome with 4918.13 and 1205.43 points, Van Avermaet with 2734.57 and 993.57 points.

However, when I look at [explanation of UCI ranking points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCI_World_Ranking#Explanation_of_the_new-for-2016_points_system) at Wikipedia ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=UCI_World_Ranking&oldid=839300417#Explanation_of_the_new-for-2016_points_system)), the points awarded for various placings are never fractions. So the best guess is that under some circumstances points are divided between several riders. Checking ranking breakdown for [Froome](https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RiderRankingDetails/43936?rankingId=1&groupId=1&momentId=26948&baseRankingTypeId=1&disciplineSeasonId=89&disciplineId=10&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0) and [Van Avermaet](https://dataride.uci.ch/iframe/RiderRankingDetails/44513?rankingId=1&groupId=1&momentId=26948&baseRankingTypeId=1&disciplineSeasonId=89&disciplineId=10&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=0) I see that in these instances the non-integer points come from team time trials. (I am not sure to which extent these links are permanent, so I will explicitly mention that Froome has 1.43 points from TTT at [Tirreno–Adriatico](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Tirreno%E2%80%93Adriatico), where Team Sky finished 3rd. Van Avermaet has 8.57 from exactly the same event, BMC Racing Team won this stage.)

Is team time trial the only possibility when points are divided between several riders? What are the exact rules how the points from TTT (or some other situations where the points are split between several riders) are divided among riders?

Comment: I think you should accept your answer, unless you are waiting for a more detailed one. I don't think there's anything more precise than the rules themselves though..

Answer (score 1):

### Points are only split among teammates, points divided evenly in TTT:

It's helpful to look at the team points [standings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_UCI_World_Tour#Team) and see that all scores are round numbers, or end in .99, .01, etc. This tells me points are only being split among teammates.

Looking at the UCI [website](http://www.uci.ch/road/results/), there have been 2 team time trials (TTT) on the UCI World Tour so far in 2018, the [Critérium du Dauphiné](http://www.cyclingnews.com/races/criterium-du-dauphine-2018/stage-3/results/) and the [Tirreno-Adriatico](http://www.cyclingnews.com/races/tirreno-adriatico-2018/stage-1/results/). BMC rider Damiano Caruso scored in both events, and you can see the fractional scoring in his [total](http://www.uci.ch/road/ranking/).

Caruso scored 8.57 points for a 1st place in Tirreno, and if you look through his team, you will find 6 other people receiving the same, for a total of 60 points across the team. He scored 3.57 points in Dauphiné, 1/7th of 25 points split across the team members who raced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant excerpt from the [UCI Regulartions](http://www.uci.ch/inside-uci/rules-and-regulations/regulations/) - [Part 2 - Road Races](http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/18/23/94/2-ROA-20180301-E-v2_English.pdf) ([Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180613112324/http://www.uci.ch/mm/Document/News/Rulesandregulation/18/23/94/2-ROA-20180301-E-v2_English.pdf)). This supports what was said in the already posted answer:

> Chapter X UCI RANKINGS
>   § 1 Elite and Under 23 Men’s UCI World Ranking
>   ...
>   Scale of points
>   2.10.008 General provisions
>
> For team time trial events and stages the points on the scale shall be awarded to the team. These points shall be divided equally between the riders finishing the event or the stage. Calculations shall be rounded to a hundredth of a point.